# Why does my try catch note the error and then stop my code after recalling the method instead of refilling values?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, while-loop, double

I would get a ...

```
 "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "d""
```

... error if i put in a "d" and the program would stop running as opposed to throwing the error and then continuing as it does in other instances

```
 String stringPointOneX = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What would you like the x value of the first coordinate to be?");

    try
    {
      double i = Double.parseDouble(stringPointOneX);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
      //////exception thrown;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! Incorrect point value. Please input values again");

      checkRectangle(); //This is the name of the method containing the code, I call it so that I can put in new values if the exception is thrown
    }
    ////////past exception;
    pointOneX = Double.valueOf(stringPointOneX);
    /////////
    String stringPointOneY = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What would you like the y value of the first coordinate to be?"));

    try
    {
      double i = Double.parseDouble(stringPointOneY);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! Incorrect point value. Please input values again");

        checkRectangle();
    }

    pointOneY = Double.valueOf(stringPointOneY);
```

////// EDITED

```
String stringPointOneX = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What would you like the x value of the first coordinate to be?");
if(Double.parseDouble(stringPointOneX) >= 0) ////This works fine as greater than or equal to 0 because that is the range of the coordinate anyway
{
  System.out.println("it works");
  pointOneX = Double.valueOf(stringPointOneX);
}
else
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! Incorrect point value. Please input values again");
  checkRectangle();
}
```

Comment: Well why don't you look at the line the exception is actually coming from? You handle the exception, but then you go on to call `valueOf()` anyways. What else were you expecting to happen when `stringPointOneX` is an invalid value?

Comment: are you belief d is a number??

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you'd like your program to do. Please be much more specific. I can tell you off the bat that catching an unrecoverable exception like this, then trying to continue the program, is a bad idea. How are you supposed to calculate a coordinate from the string "d"?

Comment: @musical_coder This exception *is* recoverable, it's just that he's not actually recovering from it. He proceeds to call `Double.valueOf()` on the same string that just failed, and does not handle an exception there. Had he actually looked at his stack trace, he may have seen this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feed back! I am sorry about the ambiguity, Im new to the site. In this part of my code I'd like to get from the user input for an x and a y coordinate (separately) through the Joption windows. I use the try catch to make sure my program does not fall apart when a user accidentally enters the wrong info (a string or char as opposed to a double). This part of my program, in other words, is just to safeguard against bad input. I want this code to catch the bad input and ask the user to redo the input so that the code runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try catch` most likely works (no reason for it not to), but then you have the lines:

```
pointOneX = Double.valueOf(stringPointOneX);
```

and

```
pointOneY = Double.valueOf(stringPointOneY);
```

outside of `try catch`, which could very well be throwing a `NumberFormatException` that is not caught.

*** EDIT ***

```
boolean validX = false;
String stringPointOneX = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What would you like the x value of the first coordinate to be?");

while (!validX) {
  try {
    pointOneX = Double.valueOf(stringPointOneX);
    validX = true; // Only comes here, if no error thrown.
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    stringPointOneX = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! Incorrect point value. Please input values again");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is that the char or whatever failed input is tested for gets forced into the Double.valueOf(StringPointOneX) and as a result the error is thrown. I was wondering if there was a way for me to extract the correct value, once it is put in by the user, after the incorrect value (the char) has been discarded as incorrect input.

Comment: So what you'd really want is a loop around asking input and trying to parse it into a number. Send him back to try again until he gives you a proper number.

Comment: That was a good idea. I tried it but when I tested for incorrect input I still got a number format exception and the program stopped going instead of asking for and using a new value.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing what you tried. Perhaps edit your question to contain that info?

Comment: What I did was test to see if the value was greater than the min value it could have in my program. This would presumably make sure it was a double or at least an int, but when i run it what happens is I get the same problem as before: throwable error and program stops.

Comment: Testing whether a `String` is greater than another doesn't make it a number. You'd still get the error. See my edited answer about how to use `try catch` blocks to your advantage here.